# Cannot subscript a value when in a func in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of integers and I can subscript just fine, but once I put it into a function, it gives me a compile error: `Cannot subscript a value of type '[Int]'`.

You can try putting this in a playground:

```
func getSomething(arr: [Int], index: Int) -> [Int] {
    return arr[index]
}
```

It gives a compile error on `arr[index]`. However, outside this function I can do items[3] just fine. Why is the function invalid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your return value is `[Int]` but `arr[Index]` produces `Int`, which is why an error is thrown for return-type mismatch.